# Select all products based on a custom attribute

Tags: magento2, database

I have a custom attribute called `PLU`, and I want to select ALL product from the database with the `PLU VALUE` in MySQL query, how can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1]  `eav_attribute` Check ur `attribute_code` for PLU & take `attribute_id`

2] Depend on your attribute type (Text, Integer, Decimal, etc..), you can find in  following tables

```
catalog_product_entity_datetime
catalog_product_entity_decimal
catalog_product_entity_int
catalog_product_entity_text
catalog_product_entity_varchar
```

Below is the query

```
SELECT * FROM catalog_product_entity_XXX WHERE attribute_id = '<Your Id>'.
```

Here `entity_id` is your Product Id

Comment: Thanks, This is absolutely working for me. :) have a great day!

Comment: It's saying i don't have enough reputation to upvote, may be i should talk more..

Comment: Do you know how to select * the SKU and PLU  and listed the way like Magento does in MYSQL? Thank you

Comment: To accept @Ankit Shah answer, you can click on the check box underneath the arrows. That will also help boost you reputation IIRC.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you will loop through retrieved products at some point, so you can try to use magento2 style to retrieve them:

```
$productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('PLU') ->addAttributeToFilter('PLU',['notnull'=> true]);
```

I assumed you already have a $productCollection object added with dependency injection or with using object manager. While the above answer is also correct, I provided this one in case you need more info about each product found